# How to calculate the nth term of a sequence which has repeating, determined differences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've covered quadratics and linear sequences and I've already got my feet into deep water with them, but I've never encountered this kind of sequence:

**3, 15, 33, 39, 51, 69**

The sequence evidently goes up by *+12, +18, +6, +12, +18* and goes on and on...

I'd like to know how to find out its nth term and what the name of that kind of sequence is.

All help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can see
$$a_{3m+1}=39+36(m-1)=36m+3,$$
$$a_{3m-1}=15+36(m-1)=36m-21,$$
$$a_{3m}=33+36(m-1)=36m-3.$$
Hence, we get
$$a_n=\begin{cases}12n-9\ \ \ \text{if $n\not\equiv 0\pmod3$}\\12n-3\ \ \ \text{if $n\equiv 0\pmod3$}\end{cases}$$
So, noting that 
$$\left\lceil\frac{n+3}{3}\div\left\lfloor\frac{n+3}{3}\right\rfloor-1\right\rceil=\begin{cases}1\ \ \ \text{if $n\not\equiv 0\pmod3$}\\0\ \ \ \text{if $n\equiv 0\pmod3$}\end{cases}$$
we get
$$a_n=12n-9+6\left(1-\left\lceil\frac{n+3}{3}\div\left\lfloor\frac{n+3}{3}\right\rfloor-1\right\rceil\right)\ \ \ (n=1,2,\cdots).$$

Comment: A well laid out and detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look at every third element of the sequence.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still stuck... Could you extend your hint please? Cheers

Comment: btw, this isn't a hw question, this sequence just came to my mind and since I love maths, I asked about how to find its nth term because I couldn't solve it

Comment: Just follow the hint. Spend more time on it. For example, what can you say about the difference of every two terms at distance three in the sequence? What can you conclude?

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will try to sit down and think about it asap.

Answer (score 1):

Given my really poor latex skills, this is the best form i could come up with:

given $n \in \mathbb{N^*}$
if: $\ \ \ \ \ \ n\ \ mod\ \ 3 = 0\ \ $  then:
$$
S_n = n*(12+18+6) + 3
$$
if: $\ \ \ \ \ \ n\ \ mod\ \ 3 = 1\ \ $  then:
$$
S_n = n*(12+18+6) - 21
$$
if: $\ \ \ \ \ \ n\ \ mod\ \ 3 = 2\ \ $  then:
$$
S_n = n*(12+18+6) - 39
$$